# How do I get tanh in jsweet?

Tags: javascript, java, transpiler, tooling, jsweet

I am using JSweet to transpile Java into Javascript and I need to use `Math.tanh()` but it's not available in the `jsweet.lang.Math` object, but I see it in the source:

https://github.com/cincheo/jsweet/blob/426e379958fc5392f8328d8e431caac0cf95653e/core-lib/es6/src/main/java/def/js/Math.java#L161

It's also missing from the API documentation:

http://public.jsweet.org/apidocs/releases/org/jsweet/candies/jsweet-core/1.2.0-20161222/jsweet/lang/Math.html

Which Math is it using and how do I use the one that implements `tanh()` ?

Comment: Have you tried using one of the [identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Definitions) for `tanh`?

Comment: I want to maintain performance of using the native `tanh` if I can since it's for distributed machine learning purposes

Comment: You're probably not going to get better performance than just using those identities.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Math.tanh(), which is an ECMAScript 6 feature, you should target ES6 in your pom.xml and add a reference to core-lib 6.

Anyway, if you feel that way, you can also use this MDN equivalent using just simple Math.exp() calls: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/tanh#Polyfill

Easy to use in JSweet :)

Hope this helped.